# How to use framework func in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, swift, cllocationmanager, ibeacon, core-bluetooth

Thanks for the Tip @davidyoung need one more help

I have a similar problem that showed in link bellow and I tried it's working but Here in App delegate you are initializing new location manager instance .. Is there any way that I can do same thing in my framework project(I have location manager initialization in sdk framework) so that developer can access that func in order to start again..

[MY IOS App is not getting any region updates when ever I restart my device any ideas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50454294/my-ios-app-is-not-getting-any-region-updates-when-ever-i-restart-my-device-any-i)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you build an iOS Framework to detect beacons, the same rules apply as if you write code in an iOS app.  You will get auto-launch behavior on beacon region entry/exit under the following conditions:

1. Bluetooth is on and Location is enabled
2. Use CoreLocation to successfully obtain background permissions with `locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()`
3. Call `locationManager.startMonitoring(for: beaconRegion)` or a `CLBeaconRegion`
4. Set up your `CLLocationManagerDelegate` to receive the callbacks somewhere in the execution thread triggered by `didFinishLaunching` of the AppDelegate.

For this to work with auto-launch, it is critical that items 3 and 4 execute as a result of that `didFinishLaunching` call.  But they don't actually have to appear inside that method itself, they can be executed inside the framework.

What you must do is **instruct users of your framework to put a method call inside `didFinishLaunching`** that calls your framework so it can take care of the bottom two items above.

Comment: Thanks David .. Will add start monitoring cal in didFinishLaunching ..Also I was thinking to use start monitoring cal in applicationDidEnterBackground and stop monitoring when it comes to applicationDidBecomeActive .. So that App will monitor regions when not in foreground.. OR is there any problem with that..?

Comment: This might not work if the user launches the app, then kills it with the task switcher or it crashes.  In those cases applicationDidEnterBackground probably will not be called.

Comment: Sorry for confusion What I am saying .. will Create Singleton Class Called LocationManager and then I will call region monitoring with in didFinishLaunching and applicationDidEnterBackground both...

Comment: OK, but you said "stop monitoring when it comes to `applicationDidBecomeActive`". If you do this, and the app never calls `applicationDidEnterBackground` (because it crashes, or the user kills it from the task switcher) it will not be auto-launched on detection.

Comment: I understand thanks for that ... Have one more problem I have to check Authentication before start monitoring cal ..So can i cal Auth service cal in didFinishLaunching and then wait for that cal back and start monitoring in that cal back. May be cal back result will come after app comes to main screen .. OR do I have to cal before didFinishLaunching return itself.?

Comment: Good question.  I don't know if you have to make the call before didFinishLaunching returns -- you'll have to test.  You might consider starting monitoring anyway, then cancelling if the auth fails.

Comment: Thanks for the input .. I tested and it will work even after return from didFinishLaunching cal .. I tried other by making locationmanager class as singleton in sdk and call it in didFinishLaunching this way also everything is working fine but when there is no beacon it won't do anything and when I touch app icon and open it the app is showing only storyboard first screen .. means i have a code in launch screen controller and it won't get triggered ..any idea

Comment: Well, `didFinishLaunching` also gets called before your view controller loads if you trigger an app launch by tapping on the app icon.  You just make sure all of your initialization paths are covered.